# Reading multiple strings in the same line

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

OK guys so I keep getting a no such element exception code and cant figure out how to debug it I'm pretty sure the problem lays in my instantiable class at

```
list.add(new Fan(
    scanFile.nextInt(), 
    scanFile.nextLine(),
    scanFile.nextLine(),
    scanFile.nextLine()
));
```

edited my code below it now works

Any ideas how to get past this?

```
public class Fan {

//fields
private static final String fileName = "fans.txt";
private String name;
private String email;
private String promo;
private int age;

//constructor
private Fan(int age, String name, String email,String promo){
    this.name=name;
    this.email=email;
    this.age=age;
    this.promo = promo;
}

//get name
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

//get age
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

//get email
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
 //get subscription
public String getPromo(){
    return promo;
}

//get existing Fan Information
public static ArrayList<Fan> getSubscribingFans() {
    //local variables
    File FanFile = new File(fileName);
    ArrayList<Fan> list = new ArrayList<>();
    //create file if it doesn't exist
    if (!FanFile.exists()) {
        try {
            FanFile.createNewFile();
            return list;
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //read file, save each line as an Fan object, store in ArrayList
    try (Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(FanFile)) {
    //edited now works
while (scanFile.hasNext()) {
            list.add(new Fan(scanFile.nextInt(), scanFile.nextLine(),null,null));
        }
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        return null;
    }
    //return list
    return list;
}
    //add a new Fan
    public static boolean addFanSubscriber(int age, String name, String email, String promo) {
        //append to file
        try (PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName, true))) {
//edited spacing inside qoutes              
pw.println(age + "    " + name + "    "+ email + "    " + promo);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Here's my JFrame code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                FanControl frame = new FanControl();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public FanControl() {
    txtEmail.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtEmail.setColumns(8);
    txtName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    txtName.setColumns(8);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 484, 326);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    lblNewLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Monotype Corsiva", Font.BOLD, 36));
    lblNewLabel.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 255));

    panel.add(lblNewLabel);
    panel_1.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    contentPane.add(panel_1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    lblAge.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    lblAge.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    lblAge.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    panel_1.add(lblAge);
    spnAge.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(18, 0, 100, 1));

    panel_1.add(spnAge);
    lblName.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    lblName.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    lblName.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    panel_1.add(lblName);

    panel_1.add(txtName);
    lblEmail.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    lblEmail.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    lblEmail.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    panel_1.add(lblEmail);

    panel_1.add(txtEmail);
    btnSubmit.addActionListener(new BtnSubmitActionListener());
    btnSubmit.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btnSubmit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnSubmit.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

    panel_1.add(btnSubmit);
    scrollPane.setBorder(null);

    contentPane.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    panel_2.setBorder(null);
    panel_2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    scrollPane.setRowHeaderView(panel_2);
    panel_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0));
    lblWouldYouLike.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    lblWouldYouLike.setForeground(Color.CYAN);
    lblWouldYouLike.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));

    panel_2.add(lblWouldYouLike);
    buttonGroup.add(btnYes);
    buttonGroup.add(btnNo);
    btnYes.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btnYes.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnYes.setForeground(Color.GREEN);

    panel_2.add(btnYes);
    btnNo.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    btnNo.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnNo.setForeground(Color.RED);
    btnNo.setSelected(true);

    panel_2.add(btnNo);
}

//update text area with current list of inventory items
private void updateList() {
    //clear text area
    textArea.setText("");
    //get current list
    ArrayList<Fan> fans = Fan.getSubscribingFans();
    if (fans == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "ERROR: unable to create or open fans file");
        return;
    }
    //create String array
    String[] fansStrs = new String[fans.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<fans.size(); i++) {
        fansStrs[i] = String.format("%10d %s \n", fans.get(i).getAge(), fans.get(i).getName(), fans.get(i).getEmail(),fans.get(i).getPromo());
    }
    //sort String array
    Arrays.sort(fansStrs);
    //display strings
    for (String s: fansStrs) {
        textArea.append(s);
    }
}

        //submit button clicked
private class BtnSubmitActionListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        //local variables
        String email = txtEmail.getText();
        int age = (int)spnAge.getValue();
        String name = txtName.getText();
        String promo;
        boolean ok = true;
        //add fan EDITED promo =
        if (btnYes.isSelected()){
            promo = "PromoTeam";
        }else{
            promo = "";
        }
        ok = Fan.addFanSubscriber(age, name, email, promo);
        if (!ok) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "ERROR: unable to add item to inventory file");
            return;
        }
        //refresh the list
        updateList();
        //clear input fields
        txtEmail.setText("");
        txtName.setText("");
        spnAge.setValue(18);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at these lines:

```
while (scanFile.hasNextLine()) {
    list.add(new Fan(scanFile.nextInt(), scanFile.nextLine(), scanFile.nextLine(), scanFile.nextLine()));
}
```

If you're input file has e.g. an empty line at the end the condition of the while loop is true, but `nextInt` won't find any `int` and as the Java documentation says:

> Throws:
>
> > NoSuchElementException - if input is exhausted

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29

The same error appears if the last data set isn't complete and you don't have three remaining lines in your document because you check only if there is one remaining line and then you read three lines.

For the first problem you may use the method `hasNextInt` to check whether there is another `int`.

Comment: i figured it out, i took out the two last .nextlines and replaced them with null and now it runs perfectly, still a little confused on how it works but atleast it does

Comment: May you show me an example entry of your file? This sounds strange ;-)

Comment: i edited my code in three different spots and put Edit in the comments where i did so if you still wanna check out how it ended up:) @Tulpenzwiebel

Comment: Two things are still unclear to me:

1) Why do you create the file in the get-method (`getSubscribingFans()`)? After creating the empty file you try to read from it, this looks a bit strange.

2) May you post your file `fans.txt`? Or an entry from it? 

Is it now working **exactly** as you proposed it to do?